# Se puede reducir más el código en python

Tags: python, condiciones

estoy aprendiendo a programar y como objetivo quiero hacer un programa que me ayude a calcular cuánto se gana una persona diario si está solo gana por comisiones de venta.
Para esto, estoy preguntando día por día y cada uno de estos días pasando los por un if-elif para al final poder tener la sumatoria de todos los días, mi pregunta es si podría reducir la cantidad de if-elif porque hacerlo por cada día generaria mucho código

```
dia_1 = int(input("Día 1 \n"))

if (dia_1 <= comision_1):
  dia_1 = dia_1 * 15 / 100

elif (dia_1 > comision_1 and dia_1 <= comision_2):
  dia_1 = (dia_1 - comision_1)
  dia_1 = dia_1 * 25 / 100 + 43500

elif (dia_1 > comision_2 and dia_1 < comision_3):
  dia_1 = dia_1 - comision_2
  dia_1 = dia_1 * 30 / 100 + 118500

elif (dia_1 >= comision_3):
  dia_1 = dia_1 * 30
```

No sé si haya una posibilidad de primero obtener todos los valores de dia (dia_1,dia_2,dia_3 ...) y al final pasarlos todos por un solo if-elif gracias

Comment: Cuando tengas varias instancias de lo mismo, usa una lista para guardarlas. Tener variables dia_1, dia_2, dia_3 no sirve. Mejor ten una lista `dias[0], dias[1], ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero es crear una función que haga el calculo. Eso facilita el trabajo posterior:

```
def calcular(ventas):
    if (ventas <= comision_1):
        ventas = ventas * 15 / 100
    elif ventas <= comision_2:
        ventas = (ventas - comision_1)
        ventas = ventas * 25 / 100 + 43500
    elif ventas < comision_3:
        ventas = ventas - comision_2
        ventas = ventas * 30 / 100 + 118500
    else:
        ventas = ventas * 30
    return ventas
```

Los `if` se pueden simplificar como se muestra.

Con eso puedes hacer un ciclo para pedir las ventas del días y guardarlas en una lista:

```
ventas = []
while True:
    venta_del_dia = int(input("Venta del día: "))
    if venta_del_dia:
        ventas.append(calcular(venta_del_dia))
    else:
        break
print(sum(ventas))
```

#### Demo

```
comision_1 = 10
comision_2 = 20
comision_3 = 30

def calcular(ventas):
    if (ventas <= comision_1):
        ventas = ventas * 15 / 100
    elif ventas <= comision_2:
        ventas = (ventas - comision_1)
        ventas = ventas * 25 / 100 + 43500
    elif ventas < comision_3:
        ventas = ventas - comision_2
        ventas = ventas * 30 / 100 + 118500
    else:
        ventas = ventas * 30
    return ventas


ventas = []
while True:
    venta_del_dia = int(input("Venta del día: "))
    if venta_del_dia:
        ventas.append(calcular(venta_del_dia))
    else:
        break
print(sum(ventas))
```

produce:

```
Venta del día: 10
Venta del día: 20
Venta del día: 60
Venta del día: 1
Venta del día: 0
45304.15

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! Me sirvió de mucho